# Sorting files in a directory by view count?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

is there a way to sort files in a directory by view count ? I have a lot videos in a folder and want to delete the bottom 20 least viewed videos. Would it be possible to sort these by view count?

PS:- Since there is no system attribute that saves the view count of a file, is there any other way of going about this.

One way that I can think of is to write code to keep view count from this point on ... and after a month,  sort the files by the view count kept by the code.

I really hope there is a better way than this

Comment: It certainly would, but I think the greater question is how you would do to determine the view count in the first place. The "view count" is not exactly an attribute that the file-system itself provides.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Precisely, I was hoping someone might be able to point out an indirect way of achieving that.

Comment: Why use `python` tag?

Comment: @mskimm would like to do this using python. Would you suggest any other tag?

Comment: @sukhvir: In that case, you'll have to describe your situation in more detail. Do you have some way at all to see a view-count of a file? Is this maintained as some kind of meta-data or something? If you currently have none, then the information most likely doesn't exist to begin with.

Comment: @Dolda2000 I have no current way to view the view count. I am using windows 7 and it doesn't store view count as far as I know. Only way I can think of keeping a count is to write a code that will store how many times a file was opened in a .txt file from today onwards. This would require me to keep collecting these stats for say a month before I can sort files based on the counts returned by my code. This is a very bad way to do this. Any easier method?

Comment: _Only way I can think of keeping a count is to write a code that will store how many times a file was opened in a .txt file from today onwards._ But how would your code _know_ when someone accessed a video file?

Comment: @Krumia good point .. i guess that method is not viable then :(

Comment: Can't you use date accessed and then delete files that haven't been accessed in more than x days? Need to take into account it may not be automatically updating this info. See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7) question.

Comment: @Shadow9043 This is the best suggestion so far. Cheers !!